Simple PDF output example in puppeteer results in TimeoutError
I am trying to print a webpage to PDF programmatically using Puppeteer in JS.I tried the following, loosely based on an example provided by the docs:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
// Or import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';

// Launch the browser and open a new blank page
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Navigate the page to a URL.
await page.goto('https://example.com');


// Configure PDF options

const pdfOptions = {
    path: "out.pdf",
};

console.log("Printing pdf");

await page.pdf(pdfOptions);

await browser.close();

console.log("DONE");

When I run this example I get the error as follows:

TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms

I've tried multiple things, including setting infinite timeout in both the pdf options as well as the launch options, to no avail.
How can I get this simple PDF output example to work using Puppeteer?

If you are on Windows see this pinned issue https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/12471

This works fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04 / Pupp 22.7.1 / Node 20. Which line throws the TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms? Are you really screenshotting example.com, or some other site? If it's another site, please provide it, because the site matters. await page.goto('https://example.com'); defaults to the "load" event, which can get stuck. Prefer using {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}.

Using the following launch options I was able to get it to work:
const launchOptions = {
    headless: true,
    args: ["--no-sandbox"]
};

I found this option in one of the reported issues in on the Puppeteer repository on github. Not sure why this is not included in the official example.

Running without sandboxes is generally not recommended for security reasons unless you absolutely trust the content you access https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox

Do you have an alternative solution?

See my other comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78682649/simple-pdf-output-example-in-puppeteer-results-in-timeouterror/78682891?noredirect=1#comment138724969_78682649
